# Forma correcta de usar una conjugación verbal

Tags: verbos, tiempos-verbales

En verbos como ir o estar, para tomar como ejemplo, podemos conjugarlos de la siguiente manera: (no recuerdo el nombre del tiempo verbal)

Fuese o fuera

Estuviera o estuviese

¿Cuál de las dos formas es la correcta? O, digamos, ¿cuál es la regla que se usa para decidir entre una forma o la otra? O, ¿el uso del uno o del otro depende del dialecto del español que se este usando?

Comment: [La respuesta de Héctor](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/13240/9112) es correcta. Tan sólo un apunte, el subjuntivo se usa para supuestos o situaciones imaginarias. En una frase tipo `Si hubiera [verbo + condición] hubiese [verbo + resultado]` suele verse alternar ambas formas (hubiera + hubiese, en cualquier orden). Ejemplo: `Si hubiese tenido suficiente dinero, lo hubiera comprado`. Sin embargo lo correcto sería usar `lo habría comprado`.

Comment: Sin embargo, es muy común escuchar Hubiera en lugar de habría. ¿Es un gran error? O, ¿se puede tolerar en el habla, pero no en lo escrito? Gracias, Blas, por tu comentario.

Comment: En las frases de tipo subordinada condicional en la que una parte está en subjuntivo (donde se establece la condición), la otra debería estar en indicativo condicional (donde se establece la consecuencia). Es un error gramatical, aunque bastante frecuente (y por tanto, entiendo que tolerable).

Comment: @BlasSoriano la Gramática tiene una excelente (e perinteresante) análisis del uso condicional de las formas -ra, que como dices, no se considera precisamente incorrecto por su uso tan extendido (tanto geográfica como históricamente... el uso se encuentra incluso en textos medievales)

Comment: Que significa (e perinteresante)? Supongo que hiper interesante?

Comment: *per-* es uno de los muchos prefijos que se puede usar para significar *muy* (como *re-*, *requete-*, *super-*, etc).  Empecé con «e interesante» y luego lo cambié a «perinteresante» sin volver a cambiar la conjunción *e* a *y*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Las dos son perfectamente correctas, de cualquier modo que las uses o las combines. El tiempo es el **Pretérito imperfecto de Subjuntivo**.

No sé si habrá algún dialecto en el que una de las formas predomine sobre la otra o se use de otra manera. En el español de España, son virtualmente idénticas y puedes usarlas de manera indiferente.